# Chef - edit data bag from a bash script

Tags: bash, chef-infra

I am trying to change values in a data bag item from a bash script. The editor is set as "ed" in the user's .bash_profile or knife.rb , but the script fails. Is it possible for the editor to be recognized this way? *edit: it fails in the terminal too when attempting to pass all the info at once.

Verbose output with heredoc:

```
#!/bin/bash -xv

knife data bag edit dbag dbagitem --encrypt << EOF
3,$s/true/false/
w
q
EOF
+ knife data bag edit dbag dbagitem --encrypt
47
?
ERROR: RuntimeError: Please set EDITOR environment variable
```

with printf:

```
printf "3,$s/true/false/\nw\nq" | knife data bag edit dbag dbagitem --encrypt
47
?
47
ERROR: RuntimeError: Please set EDITOR environment variable
```

Comment: `export EDITOR=/full/path/to/your/editor`?

Comment: the `edit` command is assumed to be for an interactive use. If you wish to automate this: `knife data bag show dbag dbagitem --encrypt -F json > /tmp/dbagitem.json && <ed part on json file> && knife data bag from file dbag /tmp/dbagitem.json`

Comment: Cyrus if your method worked that would be best as the info would never be available outside of the shell which invoked the edit. No dice though. Tensibai, that works, thanks again.